# Failed when you try to connect a W10 client to a RADIUS server by using a VPN server

Tags: vpn

I have a problem that I can't solve. I have 3 VirtualBox virtual machines: one will act as a RADIUS server (W19Server), another as a VPN server (W16Server), and the last one as a Windows 10 client from which we will connect to the VPN of the VPN server. It should allow me to access the RADIUS server with a user registered in the Active Directory database and within the group of NPS network policies.

The first machine is a RADIUS server with the roles of DNS, DHCP, Active Directory Domain Services, and Network Policy and Access Services (NPS) installed. NPS is configured here, and the VPN server is registered from which the intended users will connect.

The second machine is the VPN server, which is joined to the RADIUS server domain. It has 2 network adapters: the first one shares the same network adapter as the RADIUS server (192.168.11.1), and the second one has direct internet access with a different IP (10.0.2.1). I have installed the Routing and Remote Access role with the "Direct Access and VPN" role service. The server is configured and activated, but my problem is that when I try to connect from my Windows 10 client via VPN, it doesn't allow me to connect. I enter the username and password correctly, select the PPTP VPN type, but it tells me that the username or password is incorrect and doesn't let me connect. I have looked online for possible errors, but none of them match the issue I am experiencing.

I hope someone can help me solve this.

Comment: Please ask your question in English.

Comment: There are some issues related to NPS role work in 2019 server, which were not the case in 2016 and seem to be fixed in 2022 in my experience of installing NPS servers. Try to look into the logs on your NPS or VPN servers to further investigate the problem tho

Comment: ` I have looked online for possible errors` What do the logs on the server provide?

Comment: What records are you referring to, if you mean when the W10 client connects it does not connect, it tells me that either the username or password are not correct (when they are) and on the third attempt it says that the connection is closed